# Modules not Working across different python versions

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, mysql-python

I have two different python programs. One of the program uses the python `BeautifulSoup` module, the other uses the `MySQLdb` module. When I run the python files individually, I have no  problem and the program run fine and give me the desired output. However I need to combine the two programs so to achieve my ultimate goal. However the Beautiful soup module only runs if I open it in `python 2.7.3` and the MySQLdb runs only on the `python 2.7.4 (64bit)` version. I installed both the modules exactly the way it was mentioned in the docs. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 versions of python installed on your system, then you've somehow installed one library in each of them.

You either need to install both libraries in both versions of python (which 2 seperate versions of pip can do), or need to setup your PYTHONPATH environment variable to allow loading of modules from additional paths (like the site-packages folder of the `python 2.7.4 (64bit)` installation from the `python 2.7.3` executable).

Comment: Ive already set up the Python Path environment variable. Ive never encountered this problem before and google for a change is no that hepful